# Linux fedora - httpd package and router, how to make it work?

Tags: fedora, tcp, webserver, router

I installed HTTPD package to setup private web server in my house on one of the computers. The server is up and running, but I can't access the server from outside by using my external IP address.

I think it's because of my router, I have 3 computers in the house connected through router, and one of them is the web server, what I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward port 80 from your external IP address to this internal system running Apache.

Typically this is done through your router's web interface. The rule will say something like:

external port: 80
external IP:  Often this is referred to as WAN IP.
internal IP:  Often this is referred to as LAN IP. Something like 192.168.1.X.
internal port: 80

The rule will forward any traffic coming in on external IP @ port 80 to internal IP @ port 80. The addresses don't have to be 80, they can be any IP's. The only consideration is that the Apache web server is "listening" on this internal LAN port. This can be configured in Apache's `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Thank you, and what about security, there is any danger to open this port on my router and forward it to my webserver pc?

Comment: @user50045 - of course, you're exposing the port 80 service to the internet, so care needs to be spent making sure that your Apache instance is secured correctly.